# Can't Set Table View's Frame in animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to animate the change of a `UITableView`'s frame while using custom cells. The following code works perfectly when using the standard `UITableViewCell`. But when I use a simple custom cell with one label, something breaks.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

                     CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
                     frame.size.height += 100;

                     NSLog(@"BEFORE: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame));
                     self.tableView.frame = frame;
                     NSLog(@"AFTER: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame));
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                        NSLog(@"COMPLETED: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame));
                 }];
```

The three NSLog statements's produce this:

```
    BEFORE: {{10, 73}, {300, 0}}
    AFTER: {{10, 73}, {300, 100}}
    COMPLETED: {{10, 73}, {300, 0}}
```

Notice the frame seems to change during the animation but then once it is over the change is not seen. Again, this is only when I use custom `UITableView` cell's, when using the default cell's everything works perfectly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies in autolayout - when you changed the frame, autolayout kicks in and recalculates frames, setting it back to the previous value.

Comment: I just discovered if I delete the label on my custom cell(making it a blank UITableViewCell) then everything works correctly, at least position wise. Any ideas why this would  be?